# C# Отправка файл в Telegram Bot напрямую

Tags: c#, telegram

Использую следующий код для отправки файла

```
static string token = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Токен бота.txt");
        private static readonly TelegramBotClient botClient = new TelegramBotClient(token);
        private static readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        static string path = @"C:\Program Files\\test.zip";
        static string chatID = "";
        public async Task Start()
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(Upload());
        }
        static async Task Upload()
        {
            using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                Message message = await botClient.SendDocumentAsync(
                    chatId: UserId,
                    document: new InputOnlineFile(content: stream, fileName: path),
                    caption: "Пришёл новый файл");
            }
        }
```

Код работает если использовать через HandleUpdateAsync, то есть если ставить обработку входящих сообщений.

Но мне нужно отправлять файл напрямую как обычное сообщение. То есть программа запускается, создаёт файл и сразу отправляет в Телеграмм бота и завершает свою работу. То есть пользователь запустил бота, кнопок никак нет, а должны только приходить обработанные файлы.
Но у меня файл не отправляется, а сразу завершается работа программы

Comment: в `path` опечатка

Comment: Чтобы понять проблему, надо увидеть, как вызывается метод `Start` снаружи, как выглядит метод где этот вызов находится. Должно быть `await Start();`, а как на самом деле - загадка.